# How to add a harddisk back in raid10 array?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid10

I have a harddisk that is out of raid array. I wanted to create the partition table on sda basesd on the sdb table and I issued this command:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb --force
```

I know that the --force argument is bad here and the command is wrong, the right command was:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda
```

Now I have 2 problems, sda is still out of raid array and sdb partion table is empty.

My server looks like this now: http://pastebin.com/uMKvUwbL .

And my question is, how cand I recover sdb (I don't know if the files where deleted after I executed `sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb --force`) and how to add sda back to raid array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt would be:

**Rescue sdb**

`sfdisk -d /dev/sdc | sfdisk /dev/sdb`

sdb is still in raid, but currently this wont survive a reboot. Make sure to do this before doing anything else on this box.
Actual data on the disc is not touched while writing partition table.
After that you'll have a 3 out of 4 member raid 10, that will survive a reboot, so next action is:

**add sda back to raid**

`sfdisk -d /dev/sdc | sfdisk /dev/sda`

If `sda` has been a raid member before: 
`mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdaX` (X are all partitions)

In your paste I dont see any failed devices for the md's (already removed by you?), so I would continue to add the devices to the corresponding md's with `mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --add /dev/sdbX` as there seems to be no requirement for replacing a faulty device.

Comment: i have tried  sfdisk -d /dev/sdc | sfdisk /dev/sdb adn this is the output 

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
BLKRRPART: Device or resource busy

This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
Umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap partitions on this disk.
Use the --no-reread flag to suppress this check.
Use the --force flag to overrule all checks.

Comment: Did you checked that its currently not use? Check /proc/mounts and lsof. If you're sure, go ahead with force.